# AJAX POST successful but does not do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, electron

I am building a desktop app using electron. I want to keep the list of all the recent files opened, for this I am using jquery ajax. here is my code

```
// this function is expected to add a file entry to my json file
this.add_recent_file = function(file_id, file_name, date_opened) {
    // Execute the ajax command.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './data/recent-files.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: file_id,
            name: file_name,
            date: date_opened
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("Success");
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my sample json file:

```
[
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "name": "File.json",
        "date": "24-feb-2018"
    }
]
```

the problem is that console says 'Success' but no changes in json file. Reloading the page didn't change anything.

Comment: It's your server-side code which makes changes to files, maybe you should show that instead? With electron methods you could save the file directly on the "client-side" though.

Comment: Whenever you post something to a JSON file, it won't change itself. You need some sort of backend to do this for you. Are you running a PHP server? In this case, post it to the server and write some server code to update the JSON file.

Comment: @GerritLuimstra It looks like they are using electron.

Comment: @Teemu ah yea, just checked out the repo. I am not too familiar with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use node.js filesystem to write to the json file. check out the following code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var $ = require('jquery');

this.add_recent_file = function (object) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './data/recent-files.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (files) {
            // append the entry to the array.
            files[files.length] = object;

            // Get JSON string representation of the array.
            var str = JSON.stringify(files);

            // Now write it to the json file.
            fs.writeFileSync(recent_file_url, str);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error updating json file.');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Gerrit Luimstra, you need a backend, If you're using PHP, you might use something like this:

```
data/update.php
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$dateX = $_POST['date'];

//update database code here
```

Comment: It appears they are using Electron and not PHP as the 'backend'

Comment: Electron uses node.js

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are using AJAX to POST data to a JSON file and hope that this will update the file. This however is not the case.

What you can do instead is use Electron's file system to write changes to the JSON file.

In this case, your function would become something like:

```
this.add_recent_file = function(file_id, file_name, date_opened) {
    // Create the JSON content
    var data = {
            id: file_id,
            name: file_name,
            date: date_opened
        };

   // If you want to prettify the JSON content
   data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);


    // Write it to the file
    fs.writeFileSync('../path/to/recent-files.json', data);

}
```

This however requires you to use the node filesystem package.

Comment: That's fine but that delete the previous file content and gives syntax error while parsing json

Comment: @Mohit I would recommend simply looking at how to read/write to a file in Node.js. This has nothing to do with jQuery, or even the network for that matter.